# Different result for height when including a <!DOCTYPE>

Tags: html, doctype

In the below lines of html code, the div element extends to the entire height of the page.
Why does adding a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to it not make it take 100% height of the page? How can I get 100% height while also adding `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #menu {
            background: green;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        Menu
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What 'result' are you talking about. This needs a lot more explanation.

Comment: Why do people still think in terms of "adding the doctype"? It should be there, no questions asked. You could then take it out, but that would just be asking for trouble.

Comment: It's parsed differently by the browser, which now can expect the code to conform to a specific standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your Styles section:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The reason your content is not taking 100% height is because it is inherited from its parent element when you use percentages. The parent of `div#menu` is `body`, and `body` has no inherent height. The parent of `body` is `html`, and `html` also has no inherent height. `html`'s parent is the document/viewport itself, which **does** have inherent height of 100%.

I would also personally recommend that you use an external stylesheet for your CSS, instead.